# Changing app target name makes PNGs disappear?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Trying to change the name of the app from the development name to the production name, I renamed the target as a first stab. The PNGs in the app disappeared. I then changed the target name back to the original name and re-built, but now the PNGs are still missing.

I'm looking at step-by-step guides on project/app name changing, but I don't want to proceed until I'm unable to undo whatever this did.

Does anyone know why the images would now be missing? Even after I changed the name back?

I'm assuming there is some path based on the target name and that changing the target name triggered other changes not reversed by simply changing the target again?

Many thanks

Comment: Images are missing from where? When you click on the target you don't see them on the right side where it lists all files?

Comment: Missing during run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type in the name of your project in the finder, and double click on the project folder. Inside that folder (it may be in a folder inside that folder, like resources or something but on my computer its all in the project folder) look for .png images. These images are the images that are in your project. Delete every image inside here, or just move it somewhere else. If your app has the .png files inside the project folder, but the files are in your resources folder, you won't be able to put in the same image in your resources folder because your project (your app) says its already there, even though its just sitting there and your not using it...

So delete all the .pngs inside your project folder, then open up the app with xcode and drag the image files you need into the resources folder. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 3):

why not just use Product Name under Target -> Build Options. So you don't have to change the target name! :)

Answer (score 1):

Each file in a project can be included in a target, when you changed the target name, its possible that png files lost association to the target. right click on the folder which has the png files, and click on get info, there you will be able to select which targets this folder is included in, mark the check box for your intended target, and the files will be included again in your target.